# Is that possible to crossdomain server communication using socket.io?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

How to communicate the crossdomain serever to another server?

I've tried this code, but not worked

```
// server-side
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://example.com",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
    credentials: true
  }
});

// Crossdomain-serverside
const io = require("socket.io-client");
const socket = io("https://api.example.com", {
  withCredentials: true,
  extraHeaders: {
    "my-custom-header": "abcd"
  }
});
```

Comment: And how it went?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, it's not worked,  Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors occurred